# Neural network for geometric primitives extraction and location

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

CNN are used to automatic features extraction usually to classify images (dog, cats, etc...).
 Are there examples of how to use some kind of neural networks for geometric primitives classification and location (i.e. find lines, circles, corners, etc... in an image and their location)?

Answer (score 1):

Just google **"neural network looking for geometric in picture"** and you will find [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/object-detection-with-neural-networks-a4e2c46b4491) with  the complete code in [github](https://github.com/jrieke/shape-detection)